# What is wrong with this tiny piece of mutex code?

Tags: c++, mutex, critical-section

```
// A Mutex allows threads mutually exclusive access to a resource.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

class Mutex
{
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_mutex;

public:
     Mutex() { InitializeCriticalSection(&m_mutex); }
    ~Mutex() { DeleteCriticalSection(&m_mutex);     }

    void acquire() { EnterCriticalSection(&m_mutex); }
    void release() { LeaveCriticalSection(&m_mutex); }
};
```

Using the Entrek Codesnitch software to debug and test for any memory leaks, etc., it reports the following error:

```
InitializeCriticalSection Error: lpCriticalSection (0x000387d4) points to an invalid 
  memory location (0x00018984) Mutex::Mutex in lockmutex.h, line 29
```

Maybe all my sleepless nights are finally getting to me.  But I don't understand what it's exactly complaining about.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using placement new?  If the constructor is getting an invalid pointer you won't be able to fix that in your Mutex class.

Comment: You've chosen naming poorly here, as this really is *not* a Mutex.  A Mutex is created with a call to CreateMutex and is a synchronization object that can be named and used across all processes in the system.  A CRITICAL_SECTION only is valid within the creating process.

Comment: Semantics.  Most operating systems other than Win32-based ones refer to these as "lightweight mutexes" rather than critical sections; critical sections more correctly refer to the operation you're protecting with a CRITICAL_SECTION rather than the construct itself.

Comment: Semantics, yes, but if you're working on a Windows system (which he clearly is) and you have to communicate with another developer what you're doing, and you say "I create a mutex to protect this code section"  what are they going to automatically infer?  A Mutex, not a Critical Section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll bet you can fake out the snitch with ::memset ( & m_mutex, 0, sizeof ( m_mutex ) ); before the call to init it.

Answer (score 6):

CodeSnitch is apparently not smart enough to know that InitializeCriticalSection() *expects* to be working on a structure containing an uninitialized pointer.

Think of it from CodeSnitch's point of view.  What's the difference between what you're doing, and this:

```
struct Customer {
    char * name;
};

extern void greetCustomer(Customer* c);

class CheckoutLine {
  private:
    Customer m_customer;
  public CheckoutLine() {
    greetCustomer(&m_customer);
  }
};
```

This looks way more fishy to the *human* eye, because we infer that greetCustomer is probably going to rely on m_customer being initialized, which it obviously is not.  But semantically, this exactly the same as your code.

It's probably worth filing a bug with Entrek;  InitializeCriticalSection() is a reasonable exception to the "structures should be initialized before passing them to a function" rule.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with your class *definition*.  Where is it being used though?  A particular instance could still be used incorrectly.

The Win32 definition of a CRITICAL_SECTION includes a pointer to a 'struct _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION *'.   The OS *could* be being clever in its handling of this struct in ways that confuse the tool.